# How does Apple randomization of MAC address work

Tags: ios, mac-address

I was reading articles on how Apples randomization of MAC address has taken place. However, I wanted to know in detail how apple maintains the information of the new Mac Address of each device that is generated each time to identify the specific device. Does it enter it in the database each time it generates a new random Mac address. If that's the case wont the calls to the Database be too much to handle. I wish to implement a similar scenario thus, wanted to know the details.

Comment: Apple doesn't need to keep track of the random addresses because it used only on the local device for a short time.  Also, no one is going to give you details about anything.  What problem do you currently have that you want solved?  What code have you written?  Also it's too early to worry about performance issues with the database until you write the code.

Comment: @Black Frog Well I want to find out how to identify the device if I randomize the MAC address. I want to replicate it in developing Beacon software. If I randomize the MAC address how do I know its that specific device that's sending me the information ?

Comment: Apple only use the random address when the device is scanning wi-fi networks.  When the user joins, it uses the device address.  The random address is just temporary.  If I walk thru a mall and don't join a network, the mall cannot track me.  The next day my device is different address.  If and when I join, I lose all privacy.  And the user knows that.

Comment: There's a security vulnerability in this structure isn't there?

Comment: Why would you think there's a security vulnerability? All the device is doing is using a fake Mac when scanning wi-fi.